# Django save model and its children with ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, model, modelform, database-relations

I have such models: Article, Link & ArticleLink. Article can have many links attached to it and I need to save them from one form.

I have created all the relations and a ModelForm for Article, but the trick part is that links have two fields: Name and URL. I can't figure out what kind of form structure must be used, I tried hidden inputs with name "links[name]" and "links[url]" but did not work.

Where should I look? Is there any working example for this? Django docs does not help with this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: Yes, inline formsets looks like the closest solutions, but there are two problems - I am rendering my form manually (have to) and there is a little bit strange field naming "form-0-name", "form-1-name".

I was just thinking about looping through all the links and save them manually but I am not able to pass input array, it seems that django does not support it.